# Passing NSMutableArray between classes with method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Okay, so i hope im on the right track with this.

So this is my first class's .h file, im just declaring the method here:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)get;
```

Now lets jump into the .m file of that first class, this is the method:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)get  {  
return testArray;
}
```

I have a `NSMutableArray` called `testArray`, it is filled with 2 `NSStrings`.

I need to pass that array along to my next class

Of course in the next class i import first class.

Now i need to get the value of `testArray` in the second class. here is what im doing (not even sure if im doing it right)

```
True_FalseViewController *controller = [[True_FalseViewController alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[controller get]; //here i call the method



NSLog(@"%d", array.count);
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

What do i do from here?
The method returns a `NSMutableArray`, but i have no idea to get it into the other array called `array`.

Thanks for any help you can give,
Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do not you save return value in `array`? :

```
NSMutableArray *array  = [controller get];
```

And that's all.

Comment: When you say "no luck" that doesn't tell anyone much. Are the values not getting assigned? Are they not what you expect? Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: Set breakpoint in `get` method and check if `testArray` is not nil

Answer (score 0):

```
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[controller Get]];
```

Comment: NSLog the testArray before u return it from the get method. And also try NSLog(@"arr: %@", [controller get]) in the second class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing (alloc + init) the testArray in your first class .m??

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the testArray from the first class has a value before you return it?

Try to check if testArray has some value:

```
NSLog(@"%@",testArray);
```

It's possible that your testArray doesn't have any value to return in the first place.